# Declare Typescript type for arbitrary object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Haven't stumbled upon the right TS syntax for this with Typescript 3.7.3.

I have an arbitrary object, like:

```
var obj = {
    one: ...,
    two: ...
    three: ...
};
```

I need to generate a type of all keys from that object, creating a type like so:

```
type ObjKeys = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
```

I'd read somewhere that this syntax should work, but perhaps that was with older versions of TS.

```
type ObjKeys = keyof typeof obj;
```

Any idea?

Comment: `keyof typeof obj` should [definitely work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gWAFAW9AdgUwC4IAiEgGkxwgBcB3KYgJkqxxoAsx8jawBXfJgC+AbkyYaATwAO+CAHl4AaXxSAzkggBrNVABmtWfgPR44jAHpLRuYpVrNyElAIkIAH1L0o7ryU5ufBIgA); could you provide a [mcve] as described in [ask] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) to demonstrate the issue?  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks jcalz! Yeah you're right - works fine on the Typescript Playground. For some reason in my local build (webpack) I'm getting:

 75:36  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

I'll look into my build. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

jcalz was quite right in the comment above: the syntax was correct. In my case the problem was with my build - I was using babel-eslint as the parser, but was extending "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"). Switching to @typescript-eslint as the parser fixed it.

*.eslintrc*

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    ...
}
```